# Need help to create thread with parameters

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

im having the following that when I have lots of data it takes some time (the commit )
therefore i think maybe to create  for the method that responsible on the persist a Thread
since IM new to the thread stuff
1.how should I pass the parameters like createClassInstance
to the thread. ?
2.how should i change the call inside the main to the theard?

Thanks,

code before inside the **main**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

// Get class members
ClassHandle classMetaData = new ClassHandle();
createClassInstance = classMetaData.createClsObj(listClsObj);

// Persist data using JPA
PersistClassObject.persistObjects(createClassInstance,
        persistenceUnitName);
```

...

now I implement the runnable and i have error in the parameter ,what should i do now

```
public class TheredTest implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {


        // Persist data using JPA
        PersistClassObject.persistObjects(createClassInstance,
                persistenceUnitName);



    }

}
```

code after solution propse

```
        ClassHandle classMetaData = new ClassHandle();
        createClassInstance = classMetaData.createClsObj(listClsObj);

        PersistRunnable persistRunnable = new PersistRunnable(createClassInstance, persistenceUnitName);

        Thread thread = new Thread(persistRunnable);
        thread.start();




------


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // your persistence code referring to those arguments

        // Persist data using JPA
        PersistClassObject.persistObjects(theObjectsToPersist,
                persistenceUnitName);
    }
```

Comment: Creating a thread is not going to make that code perform any faster, and I don't see the benefit here, unless you want to create an async method. There would be a benefit on using Threads but in this case it seems to me that it is just one unit of work that you have there.

Comment: yes I want to change it to async method

Comment: you want to read some sort of concurrency tutorial first, Oracle has one here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: @RalfH-already read it...

Comment: then perhaps continue here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#threadpools This descibes how to use Executors and Runnables

Comment: you also should do benchmarking to see if your persistence work actually benefits from multithreading. Since you create transactions around every single operation, there is a good chance the DB overhead will dominate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PersistClassObject.persistObjects is *static*, there's no good way to make it a `Runnable` and pass in any parameters.  One drawback of `Runnable` (and `Callable`) is that they don't take arguments.  You'll need to make some instance each time.  e.g. very sketchy something like:

```
class PersistRunnable implements Runnable {
  final List theObjectsToPersist;
  final String persistenceUnitName;

  public PersistRunnable (List objectsToPersist, String persistenceUnitName) {
      this.theObjectsToPersist = objectsToPersist;
      this.persistenceUnitName = persistenceUnitName;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
       // your persistence code referring to those arguments
   }
}
```

Whether this new class replaces your PersistClassObject or supplements it depends on where else you use PersistClassObject.

Comment: ClassHandle classMetaData = new ClassHandle();
  createClassInstance = classMetaData.createClsObj(listClsObj);

  PersistRunnable persistRunnable = new PersistRunnable(createClassInstance, persistenceUnitName);
  
  Thread thread = new Thread(persistRunnable);
  thread.start();




------


 @Override
 public void run() {
  // your persistence code referring to those arguments
  
  // Persist data using JPA
  PersistClassObject.persistObjects(theObjectsToPersist,
    persistenceUnitName);
 }
   persistenceUnitName);
 }

Comment: that's hard to read but looks o.k.  But don't just call Thread.start(), look into thread pools or Executors etc...

Comment: Since I hard to read I have edit my question with your solution ,can you check it please if its ok?one last question what do you mean by dont just call to the start can you provide example?Thanks!!!

Comment: The example is in my comment above. Look in Vogellas excellent tutorial. Also, in your code section, you may want to limit the number of consecutive empty lines.